# Guardar Contenido de Collection en variable

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.8 y me gustaría si es posible que alguién me ayudara con el siguiente tema. Me gustaría guardar en una variable el contenidos de una collection en formato de texto.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```html
$dependentjobs = DB::table('users')->join('jobs', 'users.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
                            ->select('jobs.jobname')
                            ->where('users.topjob_id', '=', $userselected->job_id)
                            ->get();
```

Una vez he obtenido los datos de la consulta los convierto en un array

```html
if ($dependentjobs->count() > 0) {
            $jobs = $dependentjobs->pluck('jobname');
        }
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto. Lo que me gustaría ahora es poder guardar los valores del array como una cadena de texto en una variable para pasarla a la vista.

Lo he intentado recorriendo $jobs con un foreach, pero me da error.

Un saludo.

Comment: Por qué quieres mandarlos como texto?, Si al enviarlos como colección los puedes iterar en la vista

Comment: Muéstranos cómo lo has intentado (el código) y que error te dá cuando mencionas "Lo he intentado recorriendo $jobs con un foreach, pero me da error"

Comment: Hola Aprendiz. El motivo es que tengo que autocompletar un input con información que ya existe en DBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativamente, aunque ya encontraste una solución, puedes simplificar bastante las cosas a la manera Laravel.

Puedes usar [implode()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-implode) que te devolverá una cadena de texto.

> El método implode une los elementos de una colección. Sus argumentos dependen del tipo de elementos en la colección. Si la colección contiene matrices u objetos, debe pasar la clave de los atributos que desea unir y la cadena de "pegamento" que desea colocar entre los valores.

Por ejemplo, si esta consulta te devuelve una colección donde los items tienen un atributo `jobname`:

```
$dependentjobs = DB::table('users')->join('jobs', 'users.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
                            ->select('jobs.jobname')
                            ->where('users.topjob_id', '=', $userselected->job_id)
                            ->get();
```

Puedes usar `implode()` de las siguientes maneras:

```
$string_jobnames = $dependentjobs->implode('jobname', ' ; '); // separados por punto y coma
$string_jobnames = $dependentjobs->implode('jobname', ', '); // separados por coma
$string_jobnames = $dependentjobs->implode('jobname', ' - '); // separados por guión 
$string_jobnames = $dependentjobs->implode('jobname', ' '); // separados por un espacio
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Este método es mucho más simple y eficaz.

Comment: Vale, la tenía escrita a la respuesta desde ayer, pero esperaba el feedback a los comentarios en la pregunta, porque no estaba seguro de que fuese lo que estabas buscando. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

El problema que estaba teniendo es que no había declarado la variable antes de iniciar el foreach.

```html
if ($dependentjobs->count() > 0) {
            $jobs = null;
            foreach ($dependentjobs as $key) {
                $jobs .= $key->jobname .' ; ';
            }
        }
```

De esta forma si me almacena el contenido de la collection.

Un saludo y gracias.